# How to open context menu on left click instead of right click in silverlight

Tags: silverlight-4.0, contextmenu

How to open context menu on left click instead of right click in silverlight

```
<Button Content="Add" Command="{Binding AddTemplateCommand}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="14,18,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" >
    <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu >
        <toolkit:ContextMenu Name="contextMenu1" >
            <toolkit:MenuItem Name="FixedToken" Header="FixedToken" ></toolkit:MenuItem>
            <toolkit:MenuItem Name="SequenceToken" Header="SequenceTokenToken" ></toolkit:MenuItem>                             
        </toolkit:ContextMenu>
    </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```

Comment: i'd probably use a PopUp control instead, then handle the MouseLeftButtonDown event of its parent element.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
// On click
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ContextMenuService.GetContextMenu(button1).IsOpen = true;
}

// On right-click
private void button1_MouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When You have more than one button with context menu on one control, the **click event causes problems** with position of context menu.

This situation occurs when you click on button1, the menu will be open, move mouse to button2, click once, the menu will be closed and click another one without moving mouse. New menu opens on postion where was menu from button1.

To resolve this problem, You need to rebuild Silverlight Toolkit project.

1. Download source code from https://silverlight.codeplex.com
2. Open project Control.Input.Toolkit -> ContextMenu -> ContextMenu.cs
   and change

> internal DependencyObject Owner

like this:

```
internal DependencyObject Owner
        {
            get { return _owner; }
            set
            {
                if (null != _owner)
                {
                    FrameworkElement ownerFrameworkElement = _owner as FrameworkElement;
                    if (null != ownerFrameworkElement)
                    {
                        ownerFrameworkElement.MouseLeftButtonDown -= new MouseButtonEventHandler(HandleOwnerMouseRightButtonDown);
                        ownerFrameworkElement.MouseRightButtonDown -= new MouseButtonEventHandler(HandleOwnerMouseRightButtonDown);
                    }
                }
                _owner = value;
                if (null != _owner)
                {
                    FrameworkElement ownerFrameworkElement = _owner as FrameworkElement;
                    if (null != ownerFrameworkElement)
                    {
                        ownerFrameworkElement.MouseLeftButtonDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(HandleOwnerMouseRightButtonDown);
                        ownerFrameworkElement.MouseRightButtonDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(HandleOwnerMouseRightButtonDown);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Build it, change references to new dll's in your Silverlight project and set in button

> ClickMode="Hover"

```
<Button Content="Contextmenu" x:Name="button1" ClickMode="Hover" >
    <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu >
        <toolkit:ContextMenu Name="contextMenu1" >
            <toolkit:MenuItem />                         
        </toolkit:ContextMenu>
    </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```